# Angularjs caching issue for the input fields and binding data

Tags: angularjs, caching, http-headers, browser-cache, request-headers

I am facing cache issue in angularjs and i have tried

```
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
 <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
 <meta http-equiv="pragma" conten="no-cache">
```

and in request headers

```
    headers : {
                'cache': 'false',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Cache-Control': 'private',
                'Cache-Control': 'must-revalidate',
                'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0'
            },
```

If i modified input in page 1 and later if i came back to page 1 again then the modified input sometimes taking value from cache data.

How to resolve this cache problem in angularjs?

Comment: Please share your page input code, so I can filter out what is the exact program.

Answer (score 0):

You can add version to the templates which you want to prevent from caching.

To do this in angular js the simple and best way is as follows.

1. create a service

```js
app.factory('preventTemplateCache',function(){
  var threeDigitRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);
  return {
    'request': function(config) {
      if (config.url.indexOf('templates') !== -1) {
        config.url = config.url + '?v=' + threeDigitRandom;
      }
      return config;
    }
  }
})
```

here config.url is your path to template(.html)

2. Call the factory using $httpProvider.interceptors like below

```js
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('preventTemplateCache');
  });
```

**This perfectly works in all cases to prevent template caching in angular js application.**